# SQL Function Error Converting null date to String

Tags: sql, adventureworks

I am using Adventureworks2008R2 Database and trying to render the following.
I have problem with Case clause in the SQL Query.

Enddate in the table is of date datatype

```
SELECT  
         Firstname,
            Lastname, 
            Startdate,
            'END DATE' =
              CASE   
                WHEN (ENDDATE is  null) Then 'Still Working'
                ELSE EndDate
               END
FROM 
     DIMEMPLOYEE
```

This is the error I get.

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I know why it is coming but don't know easy fix?
**Update:**

What all I want is When endate is not null then replace that column with 'still Working' String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would place a `CAST` around the `EndDate` column help you here.  I think that the `CASE` statement is defining the column with a `string` datatype.

```
CASE
WHEN (EndDate IS NULL) THEN 'Still working'
ELSE CAST(EndDate AS VARCHAR)
END
```

Comment: thank you. Why I should convert it to Varchar as I am not storing the data in the database, Select should render it.

Comment: @StewieFG: The `CASE` statement needs to return the same data type, which is why you need to `CAST` to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here is the applicable [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) documentation:

> The data types of input_expression and each when_expression must be the same or must be an implicit conversion ... [and also the] **data types of else_result_expression and any result_expression must be the same or must be an implicit conversion**.

---

Answering:

> Why I should convert it to Varchar as I am not storing the data in the database, Select should render it?

The reason why this is a requirement (that CASE has a *fixed* result-type) is that each record (tuple) in the result-set *must* have the same type. The explicit *coercion* to VARCHAR, as pointed out in other answers, "widens" the data to a common type.

The schema for a result-set is separate from the data of the result-set itself and (at least in non-OORDMBS) is [invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) (the `CASE` statement itself is contravariant through implicit conversions) -- that's "just the way SQL works", and it doesn't matter if the result-set is being fed into another select/join or back to a client. The "client" could very well be another server running a remote query ;-)

Imagine this invalid result-set (which is what SQL Server is rejecting):

```
schema: {int, date}
{1: int, 2001.10.22: date}
{2: int, "Hello world": string} <-- misshaped record! must agree with schema!
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use coalesce

```
     Coalesc(cast(enddate as varchar), 'still working')
```